# Check if user is online in Firebase

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I found an example of what I need at Google Firebase documentation [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/offline-capabilities).

Still, I want to modify it a bit to make it check the presence of user every second/10 seconds or at least every minute depending on how this will affect the load on the server so I came up with this:

```
TestApp.prototype.initFirebase = function() {
    this.database = firebase.database();
    this.database.ref(".info/connected").on("value", this.isOnline.bind(this));
};

TestApp.prototype.isOnline = function(snap) {
    var i=0;
    console.log(snap.val());
    setInterval(function() {
        if (snap.val() === true) {
            console.log("connected"+(i+=10));
        } else {
            console.log("not connected");
        }
    }, 10000);
}
```

But here is what happens in the console if I run it:

> ```
> main.js:34 false
> main.js:91 User signed out
> main.js:34 true
> main.js:39 not connected
> main.js:37 connected10
> main.js:39 not connected
> main.js:37 connected20
> main.js:39 not connected
> main.js:37 connected30
> main.js:39 not connected
> main.js:37 connected40
> ```

It triggers the function every 10 seconds but it shows me both results which are `connected` and `disconnected` at the same time. (actually, there is delay around 1 second) Moreover, it completely ignores if user is logged in or not and shows me the same logs every time.

I want it to run `isOnline` method only if the user is logged in(with email and password). And if that is true `isOnline` should send request to the server if user is online every N seconds. Is there anything I can do?

*It would be much better if I could check if user is connected from the server side because I need to make some actions as long as user remains online. But I am not sure if that's possible so I think the best way is to check on frontend and trigger actions with HTTP triggers.*

Answer (score 1):

The current behavior is due to the values of `snap` being captured in the timer closures.

When you are setting up `isOnline` to trigger on `value` event, Firebase invokes the method every time the value of the key changes. In this case, Firebase invoked `isOnline` first time when it determined that the value is `false`, and then second time after login was established and the value became `true`.

Now inside `isOnline`, you are starting off timeouts. As the function was called twice with different `snap` objects, two timeouts were created. But both of them have their own `snap` objects in their closures, which are fixed to the values when `isOnline` was invoked.

As the end-result, you have two perpetual timers running which keep printing the historic `snap` values :).

As you mentioned that you only want to do something periodically if and only if the user is online, you should try this instead:

```
isOnline : function(snap){
  let test = snap.val();
  // If the user is not online,
  // check if we had the timer set,
  // as we should clear it now.
  // It essentially means user went offline.
  if (!test && this.whenOnline) {
    clearTimeout(this.whenOnline);
    this.whenOnline = null;
    return;
  }

  // If the user is not online, return.
  if (!test){
    return;
  }

  // User is online. Install the timer if we haven't.
  if (!this.whenOnline){
    this.whenOnline = setTimeout(this.doSomethingWhenOnline, 10000);
  }
}

doSomethingWhenOnline : function(){
  // whatever;

  // Cue the next timer again, notice we only install if
  // the previous instance has not been cleared by the
  // isOnline handler.
  if (this.whenOnline){
    this.whenOnline = setTimeout(this.doSomethingWhenOnline, 10000);
  }
}
```

Comment: Thx for the reply! Now I have 1 more problem. `setTimeOut`'s do not loop the function, only one message is shown in the console. And old problems are still active: even when user isn't logged in his account `doSomethingWhenOnline` triggers. So I have few questions: Why don't I use `setInterval` which actually worked before and how to fix this unauthorized triggering? I left more code here, maybe that could help(maybe `onAuthStateChanged` breaks the whole thing, or what?): https://jsfiddle.net/o0s4zgzo/1/

Comment: I mean you said that method was called 2 times but I don't understand why. Maybe it is because connection state changes only after user actually connects to the server. But then why does it output "false" every time in `interval` after the connection was established? And, lastly, how to include here user auth verification? I mean I shouldn't only check if user is online, I want also to check if user has an account and logged in with it to actually generate him some points continuously.

Comment: `isOnline` is called twice by fb because the value of the db reference changes initially from nothing to "false" and then to "true". You should not use `setInterval` as it can cause reentry if the first call is waiting on say an ajax return. You should prefer `setTimeout` for callbacks doing server operations. You can always chain the next call from the current one as I did in my code. I would recommend starting a SO chat as its impossible to reply on individual questions in comments :). Its just that I don't know how to start a chat session. Mostly it comes when we've exchanged some comments.

Comment: If you always want to evaluate if the user is connected, you can change the strategy to use a simple timer where in each call, you use the `this.database.ref(".info/connected").once("value", this.isOnline.bind(this));`. Notice that I am using `once` to ensure that isOnline is invoked only once. This will guarantee that you get the most recent snapshot in isOnline.

Comment: I don't know if I have enough reputation to start a chat. You say your example works fine, but it does not loop function with those `setTimeOut`'s. Have I misunderstood something? Because I see it completing my function only once and that's it. I think something is wrong here.

Comment: And about changing strategy. I do not understand why. So I will have timer with event listener inside which will trigger itself anyway even without timer, then why should I use timer?

Comment: Hey, why don't you check this post - https://firebase.googleblog.com/2013/06/how-to-build-presence-system.html, it's a walkthrough to implement server-side presence updates.

Comment: that is the source of the code in my project! :) But I don't understand some code from there.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/160157/discussion-between-telion-and-hazardous).